# Can a battery charger damage your car?

Tags: battery, mercedes-benz, charger

I have a 2013 Mercedes SLK that would not start one day  due to a dead battery. I called Mercedes Roadside Rescue,  they  came out and gave me a jump with a battery charger. Right after that I got an error message on my dashboard with an image showing that my hood was still up.  I told the mechanic for Mercedes Roadside Rescue. He open the hood and close it again and it appeared that the light has gone off. As I pulled out my driveway and started to drive again I noticed that the light came back on. Also I noticed that my heat wasn't working at all. It wouldn't even turn on nothing. Is it possible that it could be due to being jumped improperly or maybe a faulty battery charger box?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Using a helper person does the hood message reliably done and go if you push on the switch that detects whether the hood is open? Have you tried checking/replacing the fuse that protects the cabin electrics/heater system?

Comment: Thanks for replying to me. The hood message appears when I put the car in gear and start to drive. So if I'm at a traffi light it comes on right as I'm about to start driving again. No I haven't had the fuse checked.  I'll try that. Thanks.

Comment: More likely than by the charger, the issues were caused by the power outage. Some control units may lose settings or misbehave otherwise when battery voltage is irregular, as is the case when trying to start a car with a near-dead battery. The fix is to hook up a diagnostic device, check for stored errors in any of the control modules, and reset or reprogram them (or have a repair shop do that for you).